# ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, node.js

Помогите пожалуйста, ищу по id конкретную единицу в списке, в которой нужно обновить 1 поле характеристики, в характеристики приходит обьект, c обновленными данными, но суть в том что мне шваркает ошибка (Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'). Попытка юзать REPLACE INTO, заменяет все данные на null, и обновляет поле характеристик, а мне нужно апдейтить только одно поле, как победить проблему?

```
CREATE TABLE drillingRigs  (
    id INT(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(150),
    yearOfIssue DATE,
    beginOfWork DATE,
    endOfWork DATE,
    latitude FLOAT,
    longitude FLOAT,
    images VARCHAR(300) COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    characteristics VARCHAR(300) COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;


const upDateCharacteristics = (id, data) => {
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: ''
        });

        connection.query(`UPDATE drillingRigs SET id = ?, characteristics = ?`, [id, jsonData], (err, result) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(result);
        });
        connection.end();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то у вас тут странное. Зачем вы в `SET` пихаете `id`? Его в `WHERE` надо:

```
connection.query(`UPDATE drillingRigs SET characteristics = ? WHERE id = ?`, [jsonData, id], (err, result) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    resolve(result);
});
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо, пару дней как с mysql знаком, не совсем понимаю что делаю)

Comment: @SiergiejVatz рад помочь)